# Restrict access to applications by password protecting them

Tags: windows, password-protection

I have need to restrict access to specific applications in windows 7.

I'd like to be able to password protect the applications rather than use for example windows account restrictions but worst case that's fine too.

I want free programs for this, if there's no good programs could someone explain how to set up the user accounts in to achieve this?

I mainly want to lock all browsers. I will also want restriction to installing new programs.

Any suggestions and guidance on this subject?

Edit: it's fine that the applications (when unlocked) modify the harddrive. I just want the lock so you have to know the password to execute the program.

Edit: I'm using Windows 7 home edition

Answer (score 0):

Which version of windows are you using? 
If you are using  Ultimate and Enterprise versions of Windows 7

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/6317/block-users-from-using-certain-applications-with-applocker/

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 home edition sadly.

Comment: how about parental controls option, such as UAC.