# Restrict access to applications

Tags: windows-7, restrictions

I would like to prevent for a specific user from being able to execute applications (.exe, .msi, .vbs) on every drive of the PC (including removable drives), with the exception of the folders C:\ProgramFiles\, and C:\Windows.
This is because of viruses; especially if someone downloads an .exe and accidentally executes it.

I have Windows 7 Professional. I found a very similar thread ([Applocker](https://superuser.com/questions/852736/restrict-access-to-applications-by-password-protecting-them)), but Applocker didn't work for me.
I copied putty.exe under C:\Temp\ and did the steps for user Foo (also started AppIDSvc), described at the link, PC restarted, but it hadn't any effect; Foo was able to execute putty.exe.

Could you help me to solve it?

Is there maybe any other alternatives? It must not be Applocker...

Comment: well, you are asking for a MAC sublayer for windows, but there isn't really one. you should probably be looking at emet. Note that Win7 mainstream support has ended, so if you are this worried about malware, you should consider upgrading your OS.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control  https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/06/microsoft-bringing-emet-back-as-a-built-in-part-of-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

You can block execution of programs from certain folders by denying the NTFS permission `Traverse folder/execute file`. I've done this on specific folders such as the Downloads folder with good success. I'd be cautious about applying such a deny permission to an entire directory tree however.

If you decide to do this, do it as follows do that you can easily disable the restriction or restrict different users at will:

1. Create a local group named **Disable NTFS execute users**
2. Deny the permissions to *that* group
3. Make your user(s) a member of that group

To lift the restriction, simply remove the user from the group.

Keep in mind that a non-administrator user can edit NTFS permissions on any folder of which they're the Owner. Also, Administrators can **always** edit permissions and defeat this strategy.

Note that this approach only works for actual executables. For example, .vbs script files are not programs themselves and are not blocked by this. They're read then executed by the wscript.exe or cscript.exe executables which live in the Windows directory structure. Same goes for other types of scripts, including PowerShell.

Comment: Thanx for your answers. I'm experiencing with Parental Control. There is a list of all currently installed programs. I checked all of it. After it, when i copy a new .exe in any folder of C:\, i get a message: "Application is blocked due to restrictions."
NTFS permission seems to be also good. I have a question: can i disable the exec-permission for the whole drive C:\ ? (under Linux i can do it for a root directory) If yes, does it means, if the user creates a new folder under C:\, this also won't have the exec-permission?

Comment: If you disable execute permissions for the entire C: drive you will render the machine inoperable for the affected user, since Windows and applications would not be able to run their code.

Comment: You're right :-) I meant the entire drive C: with the exception of the folders Windows\ and ProgramFiles\. Does this have any other sideeffects?

Comment: It's a pretty non-standard way of accomplishing what you're after, so I can't vouch for this approach (or its side-effects) from experience. But if you do it the way I've laid out here, it's easy to remove the affected user from the restricted group should you encounter unwanted side-effects. And yes, I'd be prepared for them.

Comment: Maybe this tool would be the right for me [Inteset Secure Lockdown](https://www.inteset.com/secure-lockdown-standard-edition) ? Unfortunately it's not free. Found [here](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/how-do-i-allow-windows-7-users-to-run-only-specific-applications/) .